# "As the song says"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I want to quote something from a song and say something like "this is just like in this song." What is the correct phrasing between the following sentences?

> But, as song says, "now you have it, now you don't."
>   But, as THE song says, "now you have it, now you don't."

Based on some answers I added an extra question.

Would the following sentence be more correct?

> But, just like in the song, "now you have it, now you don't"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to a particular song, so you have to use the definite article

> But, as the song says, "quote".

You would not use the article if you were talking more in general, for instance:

> As pirates say, "arrrrr!"

Answer (score 1):

But as THE song says, "quote" is the proper way to say it. =) you need an article there to reference the song.

However, a formal way to write it would be

> This is reflected in the song through the line: "quote"

I hope this helps. =)

Comment: This seems overly formal. I see no problem with either *as the song says* or *as the song goes*.

Comment: It is very common to use *say* in a figurative way. For instance: *the recipe says to add 500ml of water*, *the book says xxxx*, *the software says it cannot find the file*.

Comment: @jackgill, @nico, what the OP has written is perfectly fine, and I agree with both of you, I did answer the question. I'm just offering another take on it.